# Tripit + GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, oauth

I have a iPhone app. I'm trying to add tripit support using GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch. It use 4 NSURL:

```
NSString *myConsumerKey = kTripItAPIKey;        // pre-registered with service
NSString *myConsumerSecret = kTripItAPISecret;  // pre-assigned by service

GTMOAuthAuthentication *auth = [[[GTMOAuthAuthentication alloc] initWithSignatureMethod:kGTMOAuthSignatureMethodHMAC_SHA1
                                                                            consumerKey:myConsumerKey
                                                                             privateKey:myConsumerSecret] autorelease];

// setting the service name lets us inspect the auth object later to know
// what service it is for
auth.serviceProvider = @"Tripit";

NSURL *requestURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.tripit.com/oauth/request_token"];
NSURL *accessURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.tripit.com/oauth/access_token"];
NSURL *authorizeURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://m.tripit.com/oauth/authorize"];
NSString *scope = @"https://api.tripit.com/scope";

GTMOAuthAuthentication *auth = [self myCustomAuth];

// set the callback URL to which the site should redirect, and for which
// the OAuth controller should look to determine when sign-in has
// finished or been canceled
//
// This URL does not need to be for an actual web page
[auth setCallback:@"https://api.tripit.com/OAuthCallback"];

// Display the autentication view
GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch *viewController = [[[GTMOAuthViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithScope:scope
                                                                                         language:nil
                                                                                  requestTokenURL:requestURL
                                                                                authorizeTokenURL:authorizeURL
                                                                                   accessTokenURL:accessURL
                                                                                   authentication:auth
                                                                                   appServiceName:@"AppName"
                                                                                         delegate:self
                                                                                 finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)] autorelease];

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:viewController
                                       animated:YES];
```

I was reading official documentation and I found request, access and authotize URL but it doesn't talk anything about "scope" and OAuthCallback url ¿?. When I try to access I receive "Access Request Failed" message from Tripit site. What's wrong? :-(

Answer (score 0):

I will answer this in case anyone else runs into the same problem.

You will need to slightly modify Google's project to use it with TripIt. TripIt is expecting you to send the oauth_token, as well as the oauth_callback in the request url. Log the request that the UIWebview is loading to see exactly what is being sent to the TripIt servers.

In your case, it probably looks like this:

```
https://m.tripit.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=<THE TOKEN HERE>
```

When it should look like this:

```
https://m.tripit.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=<THE TOKEN HERE>&oauth_callback=<YOUR CALLBACK URL>
```

Append the callback URL to the original request and you should see the login/authorize screen loading, instead of "Access Request Failed".

Also, this may help anyone confused about integrating with TripIt and OAuth 1.0.
http://blog.andydenmark.com/2009/03/how-to-build-oauth-consumer.html